# instagram login with hello.js

Tags: javascript, hello.js

I tried to login instagram with hello.js, but it never direct to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize, otherwise it directs to my redirect url immediately, so I cannot get access token. Here's my code:

```
    hello('instagram').login({redirect_uri : instagram_redirect_url, 
    scope: 'basic, publish'}, function(e){
                if(e.error){

                }else{
                    var instagram_access_token = 
    hello('instagram').getAuthResponse().oauth_token;
                    var instagram_secret = 
    hello('instagram').getAuthResponse().oauth_token_secret;
                    console.log(instagram_access_token);
                    console.log(instagram_secret);
                }
            });
    hello.init ({
        instagram: instagram_client_id
    });
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to change `response_type` to `token`:

```
hello.init(
    {
        instagram: INSTAGRAM_ID
    },
    {
        redirect_uri: helloOAuthCallback,
        popup       : {
            location: 'no'
        },
        oauth_proxy : oauthproxy_url,
        response_type: 'token'
    }
);
```

Now it works for me.